# Will Over-advancement cause genetic/physical degradation?

Tags: evolution, technological-development

This is another question pertaining to my super-intelligent humanoids:

Assuming that their race successfully developed extremely advanced, easily available prosthetics, while they were morally of the ground that "If its better, its a fallacy to not use it" - so much so that most of their population, if not all, would be augmented ala Deus Ex:

Would they begin to "devolve" physically over time? Would each generation born slowly, gradually grow more and more frail as they lose track of their 'real' bodies?

Comment: May I ask what happens to your gene splicing research program? try pressuring the government harder instead of playing with toys.

Comment: the biologist in me must speak up here!  first, there is no such thing as devolving, a species may grow smaller, less intellegent, or weaker, but only if doing so helps them to better survive and reproduce!  Also, evolution happens on geological scales, thousands of generations.  There wouldn't be enough time to evolve differently then we are now.  Frankly, at the exponential rate our technology grows, were most likely either destroy ourselves, destroy our technology, or evolve to a higher plane of existence in some manner long before enough time passes for evolution to significantly change us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is really anything you please.  It's your story.

For some prior art, considering the Azgard from SG-1, who suffered greatly due to their genetic degradation.  Alternatively, consider the work of the Bene Gesserit in Frank Herbert's Dune, who sought to address the issue.

It's also reasonable to say they wont grow more frail, because we may eventually find an effective way to emulate all of the benefits of traditional genetic mixing (such as sequencing genomes and doing the mixing in computers).

Comment: Hmm. Computer 'parents'. I don't know why I didn't think of that. It does seem like something this asshat species of mine would do. Thanks!

Comment: 60 minutes did a piece a few weeks ago about labs that can select embryos that aren't effected by a list of generic disorders.  You could easily extrapolate to full on eugenics for story purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit like us humans, in a way though, isn't it? We've advanced in medicines (and soon, advanced prosthetics). Evolution won't really run backward in the sense of "devolution", as it only moves forward; taking what currently exists and adapting it to survival. If those in the population who are frail continue to breed, and those not frail cease to breed, then the population will eventually evolve into frailty. However, like modern humans now, many people breed and thus few genetic lines are erased.

Simply, the answer is "No" because they will not become more frail unless it is bred in; evolution will "slow down" if anything from a lack of natural selection.

NOTE: The people may still be frail, though. With advanced prosthetics, the need for physical fitness decreases, and people would not be as muscular as they would normally have to be in order to perform physical tasks.

Comment: You aren't considering mutations. Negative mutations occur much more frequently than positive mutations. In the absence of any selection against the negative mutations they will accumulate in the population and cause a gradual decline in fitness. It will be very slow, but in the absence of purifying selection or genetic manipulation the human genome will change randomly and the net result of those changes will be negative.

Answer (score 1):

They might become dependent on the technology but Scifi rarely captures just how incredibly long notable genetic degradation would take.  We're talking tens of thousands or hundreds of thousands of generations to lose a lot.

But keep in mind, there will still be some form of selective pressure. Who ends up having more kids growing up in a safe environment in the new world?

There may be less pressure to be able to run fast on your biological legs but strong pressure against anyone who gets terrible migraines from the cerebral implants. The ability to run down a gazelle may become less important but the ability to be charming and physical beauty may still be selected for.

But unless your species is technologically static for the millions of years needed they'll still be learning how to deal with new problems, developing new tech and applying new methods of physical and genetic engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something in the environment that is a significant selection pressure, the overall genetic stock won't change. The pressure to avoid being eaten won't exist in this world.

**Sexual Selection**

An interesting line of thought would be what happens when the culture conflicts with itself over enhancements.  The OP states that "anything better will be used" but what if all those with visible prosthetics are less desirable than those who's prosthetics cannot be seen?

Remember that sexual selection is based are one or both genders doing something hard that proves their fitness. In humans we see this as high emphasis on physical fitness or leanness, advanced education, material possessions, good looks, great hair, etc.

In this world, prosthetics are easy so having them is no proof of fitness. Having expensive or powerful ones may prove fitness. Maintaining a healthy biological body would still be hard thus making it something that can be selected for. If this is the case then degradation of the physical condition of the population is unlikely to go down.